OLE DB OR ODBC error: We cannot convert the value null to type Table
This error pops up when I select Apply in Power Query in Power BI desktop.
I have a project which involves processing a number of PDF files to extract relevant information.
I have a report file (fnReport) which will combine about 60 of the 100-150 files that are in the project.
If I hard-code the query names, there is no problem either combining the tables, or Applying them back to the Power BI desktop.
I though it would simplify things, rather than hard-coding all of the names, to generate a list of queries (using #sections) and then I could simply select the particular queries I wanted to include in the report.
There are no errors in any of the queries. But when I click Apply, an error pops-up.
If I replace AccountsList[Value] with a hard-coded list of the relevant queries (all of which output a table), there is no error in selecting Apply.
This poster had the same problem, but he developed a different solution which doesn't work for me.
Any thoughts as to what is going on? I suspect there is some issue having to do with the reference being generated by the #sections keyword.
Edit: To reproduce error
in Power BI, paste the following into three separate blank queries
Table1
Table.FromColumns(
        {{"abc","def"}}
        & {{"efg","jkl"}},
        type table[A=text, B=text])

myList
let
    Source = #sections[Section1],
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Converted to Table", each ([Name] = "Table1"))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"

myReport
let
    report = Table.Combine(myList[Value])
in
    report

Deselect enable load on Table1 and myList.If you don't do this, you will simply get more error messages
Then select Apply or Close and Apply
Even though there are no errors in the queries, this action will return the error message:

If, in myReport, you replace myList[Value] with {Table1}, no error occurs and myReport is successfully applied.
